# Using Groupby and remove groups that contain certain characteristics

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Instrument':['AAA','BBB','BBB','BBB','BBB','BBB','CCC','CCC'], 
'Date':['2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-03'],
'Time':['00:00:00.000','00:00:00.000','07:01:04.231','09:47:07.136','09:57:13.757','09:58:26.841','09:28:31.161','09:28:43.562'], 
'ID': [5939908167998967312,5958912126973154535,5958912126973154535,5958912126973154535,5969584811466071582,5969584811466071582,5970013075540072892,5970013075540072892]})
```

I wish to groupby Instrument, Date and ID and remove the group that contain Time 00:00:000 in the same ID group.

The desired output is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df_remove_group = pd.DataFrame({'Instrument':['BBB','BBB','CCC','CCC'], 
'Date':['2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-03'],
'Time':['09:57:13.757','09:58:26.841','09:28:31.161','09:28:43.562'], 
'ID': [5969584811466071582,5969584811466071582,5970013075540072892,5970013075540072892]})
```

I can only code until this part
`df.groupby(['Instrument','Date','BidID']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Time'], ascending = True)).reset_index(drop=True)`

My code could be useless for the output that I want to achieve. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) for groups where the minimum `Time` is not `'00:00:00.000'`

  - This answer assumes `Time` is `str` type, as shown in the sample data.
  - [`pandas.Series.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) will correctly evaluate `'00:00:00.000'` as the minimum value, because `'0'` evaluates as less than other numeric strings.
- Also see [pandas: Filtration User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration)

```py
dfg = df.groupby(['Instrument', 'Date', 'ID']).filter(lambda x: x.Time.min() != '00:00:00.000')

# display(dfg)
Instrument        Date          Time                   ID
       BBB  2020-01-02  09:57:13.757  5969584811466071582
       BBB  2020-01-02  09:58:26.841  5969584811466071582
       CCC  2020-01-03  09:28:31.161  5970013075540072892
       CCC  2020-01-03  09:28:43.562  5970013075540072892
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
m = df['Time'].ne('00:00:00.000').groupby([df.Instrument,df.Date,df.ID]).transform('all')

df_filter = df[m]

Out[73]:
  Instrument        Date          Time                   ID
4        BBB  2020-01-02  09:57:13.757  5969584811466071582
5        BBB  2020-01-02  09:58:26.841  5969584811466071582
6        CCC  2020-01-03  09:28:31.161  5970013075540072892
7        CCC  2020-01-03  09:28:43.562  5970013075540072892
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this on my large dataset and it returns " bad operand type for unary ~: 'float' ". May I know how to fix it?

Comment: @ShaunLim: I changed to `ne` and `all` without using `~`. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])

s = df.groupby(['Instrument', 'Date', 'ID'])\
      .filter(lambda s: ~s['Time'].eq(pd.Timedelta(0)).any())
```

Result:

```
  Instrument        Date            Time                   ID
4        BBB  2020-01-02 09:57:13.757000  5969584811466071582
5        BBB  2020-01-02 09:58:26.841000  5969584811466071582
6        CCC  2020-01-03 09:28:31.161000  5970013075540072892
7        CCC  2020-01-03 09:28:43.562000  5970013075540072892
```